# Can this SDRAM be used with STM32F7?

Tags: stm32, memory, sdram, dram, stm32f7

I have STM32F7 (which has a Flexible Memory Controller capable of interfacing SDRAMs) and I want someone to check if it is able to interface this SDRAM - IS42S32800D (http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1275293.pdf).

I have checked and it seems ok, but I want to be sure, because I have "one shot" to buy and do the PCB.

Answer (score 1):

According to Reference Manual for STM32F74x and STM32F75x - RM0385, the micro series can handle all the signals of this SDRAM:

[image: SDRAM Signals STM32F7xx]

But you have to make sure that the exact partnumber you're using has all the signals externally accesible.

For example, I'm using STM32F746BG, LQFP208, and it has all the signals for the data and addresses.

It's been a long time since you asked, but I hope it can help.

Comment: This is a first step, but the availability of the signals is not a guarantee that these two chips can work together. There are sometimes some discrepancies in the signal timings, or in the supported SDRAM configurations by the MCU that create some incompatibilities. Actually, it is very hard to answer this question with confidence unless you really have tried this exact combination.

Comment: Is there any SDRAM or a controller not JEDEC compliant these days? If it not work, it'd be really a surprise for me...